# Pegar dados de um arquivo xlsx

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando fazer um código que leia os dados de um arquivo excel e escreva-os no console. Para isso estou usando o [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs) mas estou tendo um problema. Toda vez o meu código retorna "Undefined" no meu console, a menos que eu coloque o `console.log` dentro do `onreadystatechange`, mas de forma alguma esta arrow function me retorna os dados do arquivo xlsx. Oque estou errando?

```
var pega_dados_excel = () => {
    var softwares_instalados;

    var url = "test.xlsx"; // Inserir o nome do Arquivo excel(xls ou xlsx)

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Inicia a requisição
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        var data = new Uint8Array(req.response);
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "array" });
        var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
        var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
        
        softwares_instalados = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet));
    }

    req.send();

    return softwares_instalados;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log(pega_dados_excel());
});
```

EDIT1: Depois da alteração feita, sugerida pelo Cmte Cardeal o console ficou da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que o problema seja porque o `onreadystatechange` é assíncrono, ou seja, seu código vai executar de cima pra baixo de forma sincrona, enquanto o `onreadystatechange` vai levar um tempo pra ser chamado, logo o seu `softwares_instalados` vai ser `undefined` sempre, porque antes de o `onreadystatechange` ser chamado, a funcao ja deu o retorno de `softwares_intalados`.

Minha dica seria, talvez, trabalhar com uma funcao de `callback`passada por parâmetro para a sua função `pega_dados_excel` (`var pega_dados_excel = (callback) => {...}`), que será executada quando a operação assíncrona terminar. Quando essa função de `callback` for executada, vamos passar os resultados como parâmetro para ela. Neste caso chamei de `softwares` e vamos passar o resultado (`softwares_instalados`) para ela.

Vou mostrar um código que talvez possa funcionar. SE FUNCIONAR, comente minha resposta pra que eu lhe explique, mas acho que o código fala por si só:

```js
var pega_dados_excel = (callback) => {
  var softwares_instalados;

  var url = "test.xlsx"; // Inserir o nome do Arquivo excel(xls ou xlsx)

  var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Inicia a requisição
  req.open("GET", url, true);
  req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
  
  req.onreadystatechange = function(){
      var data = new Uint8Array(req.response);
      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "array" });
      var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
      
      softwares_instalados = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet));

      // quando tivermos uma resposta, executamos a funcao de callback.
      callback(softwares_instalados) 
  }

  req.send();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  // dentro de 'pega_dados_excel', vamos executar nossa funcao de callback
  // repare que 'softwares' é o parametro que passamos para 
  // 'callback(softwares_instalados)'

  pega_dados_excel((softwares) => {
    console.log(softwares) // quando tivermos o retorno, damos um console.log()
  });
});
```

Tente fazer os teste desse script que coloquei. Se funcionar eu posso explicar, se não, eu apago minha resposta e penso um pouco mais na solução. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado, entendi como vc fez e funcionou no meu teste, porém está sendo retornado 3 `console.log`, sendo dois vazios e o ultimo corretamente, sabe me dizer o porque ? Vou deixar um print na pergunta

Comment: como esta seu codigo? posso dar uma olhada.

Comment: Atualizei o código na pergunta

Comment: ah sim, a explicacao e por causa do `readyState` do documento, creio eu. como mostra a  [documentacao da mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState), "Retorna "loading" enquanto document está carregando, "interactive" quando foi carregado porém seus sub-recursos (como imagens, por exemplo) ainda não, e "complete" quando foi totalmente carregado.", entao sao 3 etapas diferentes, e por isso os 3 `console.log()`. Se foi respondida sua duvida, retorne o codigo da sua pergunta para como estava inicialmente e um voto se minha resposta foi util :D

Comment: Faz sentido... coloquei um if dentro do `onreadystatechange` para verificar se já está OK e funcionou perfeitamente. o if ficou assim: `if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)`. Muito obrigado pela ajuda :)